# Module Not Found: Can't Resolve Swiper React JS scss

Tags: npm, sass, compiler-errors, npm-install, failed-installation

I've been working on my code when suddenly it stopped updating things so I have restarted and npm start,
suddenly I'm getting:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-id-swiper/lib/styles/scss/swiper.scss' in 'C:\Users\Fill\Desktop\ammelias_Main_file\ammelias-react\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

Is there a way to fix it? I've tried deleting node_modules folder and npm install but that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

The latest version 4.0.0 doesn't have the scss modules, you'll have to import them from swiper package.

```
@import '~swiper/swiper.scss';
```